# Cannot launch Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I cannot run the Android SDK manager or AVD manager from the Android Studio pulldown (Tools,Android, SDK Manager)

Error Message:
ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "D:\Android\Android Studio\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: Cannot run program "D:\Android\Android Studio\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I also cannot launch it when I try to run android.bat

Error Message:
Windows cannot find 'D:\Android\Android Studio\sdk\tools\android.bat

I installed Android Studio beta v0.8
Windows 7 machine 
I am logged on as administrator
I am running Android Studio as administrator
When I right click on android.bat and select Run as Administrator I get an Open With dialog box
When I right click on android.bat and select properties, Compatibility, the Privilege Level run as admin checkbox is greyed out. The permissions for all the users is everything except Special Permissions (and I cant change that)
I also tried making the whole folder run as admin but that didn't seem to work.

I was able to get the SDK manager to work by finding the SDK Manager.exe from an old install of the SDK and copying it to the new SDK folder and running it.

Comment: I cannot run any .bat file by the way.

Comment: None of these things work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288652/failed-to-start-avd-manager-in-android-studio-0-4-2-using-windows-8-1

Comment: perhaps its a bug since you are using a beta software.I feel like you solved your own question.what i can say is that your android.bat is failling du to the space on "android studio" folder name it should be "AndroidStudio" without space to work